# I was going on vacation before the furlough day

Tags: income

We have to take a furlough day at my agency. Before the agency setup the date, I requested vacation and it was approved. Should I get paid for it since it was long before the date set.

Comment: are people who didn't pre-schedule for vacation allowed to take the furlough day as vacation or sick?

Comment: In the (USA) government email broadcasts I get related to such events it always says that people already on/schedule for leave are required to use their leave as scheduled (i.e. they do not get the furlough in lieu of using time off).   You don't give enough information to tell if that applies to you or not.

Comment: Is this US government agency?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable here, nor do I think this is even the right Stack to ask this in ([workplace.se] is better).  You should ask your HR rather than us, as it's entirely up to company policy.

Comment: @JBC - I'm confused by your phrase: "they do not get the furlough". as if it's some sort of advantage. Typically furlough is unpaid, so if you are on *paid* leave (vacation) and were forced to keep it, you actually get paid more, which seems unlikely. If you're referring to *unpaid* leave, then it wouldn't make a difference if it spanned a furlough day.

Comment: @TTT Around here we occasionally have days where something happens and there is an office closure or part of the workspace is rendered unusable (e.g. snow, fire).  In this case the government instructs the employees not to come to work, but they _are_ paid for however many hours they're normally scheduled to work that day.  However, if they're already on or scheduled for leave on the day this happens to occur then they must still expend leave and do not get that "extra" time off.  For everyone else it's basically a bonus day of paid time off.

Comment: @TTT Here's an excerpt of a recent event we had as an example (fire in part of the building):  `Employees who do not have an approved telework agreement, will be granted excused absences, pending approval by their supervisors, for today.`  Excused absences are defined as `Administrative leave (also referred to as “excused absence”) is an administratively authorized absence from duty without loss of pay or charge to leave.` per [OPM](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/leave-administration/fact-sheets/administrative-leave/)

Comment: Per normal utilization of the word, "furlough" refers specifically to *unpaid* days off, typically due to cost-cutting measures.

Comment: @JBC - Like Joe and I mentioned, most likely what you're referencing would not apply to "furlough".

Comment: @TTT @Joe That's why I said `You don't give enough information to tell if that applies to you or not.` and why this was a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't get paid for that day, but assuming you have a set number of vacation (or PTO) days, then you would gain an extra vacation day. For example, if you take a week off, normally you would use up 5 of your vacation days for that week, but if one of those days is a company furlough day, then you would only have used 4 vacation days instead of 5.